# jQuery ajax form not submitting when no errors exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phpmailer, ajaxform

I have a form submission using jQuery & PHPMailer(). If errors exist then they will show above the form, such as "Name is a required field", however when all fields are filled correctly the form still shows an empty `alert alert-danger` box at the top and doesn't submit.

**jQuery**

```
var form = jQuery("#contact-form");
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:      '/process-contact.php',
        type:     'POST',
        data:     form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        jQuery('#messages').removeClass();
        if (data.code === 1) {
            form[0].reset();
            jQuery('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success');
            jQuery('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
        } 
        else {
            jQuery('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger');
            jQuery('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        jQuery('#messages').html(data.message);
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#messages").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="contactForm" id="contact-form" name="contact-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label> 
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <button class="btn btn-skin pull-right" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where does this `alert alert-danger` box come from? not in any code you've *shown*

Comment: You could console.log the data, and see what's in there. The error probably lies in the form-handling, not in the JS.

Comment: @JaromandaX its in a div above the form, <div id="messages"></div>, this is where the error/success messages appear

Comment: and where's the code that does this majicks?

Comment: @JaromandaX it's a PHPMailer script

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `alert-danger` after each click

```
form.submit(function(e) {
 jQuery('#messages').removeClass('alert-danger');
 ........
```